# Opening closed app from Widget in Android/Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, widget

I have a Flutter app and an associated homescreen widget. I can click on the widget and it will open the app, but only if it's in a *minimised* state.

The following is the relevant code from the widget class, QuickEntryWidget

```kotlin
class QuickEntryWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    private val myOnClick = "myOnClickTag"

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        // Perform this loop procedure for each widget that belongs to this
        // provider.
        appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->
            // Set up a click listener that sends a message to Flutter when the widget is clicked
            val views = RemoteViews(
                context.packageName,
                R.layout.quick_entry_widget
            )

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetLayout,
                getPendingSelfIntent(context, myOnClick))

            // Update the widget with the new layout
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }

    private fun getPendingSelfIntent(context: Context?, action: String?): PendingIntent? {
        val intent = Intent(context, javaClass)
        intent.action = action
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (myOnClick == intent.action) {
            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            pendingIntent.send()

            val channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "your_channel_name")
            channel.invokeMethod("your_method_name", "")

        }
    }
}
```

Explaining the code in my own words, it:

Sets up click listeners on each widget the user has. These click listeners are intents which get fired to its own class when clicked, and call onReceive with the Intent. This itself sends another intent, which opens the app (`pendingIntent.send()`) and sends a message to the Dart code using `invokeMethod`

This all works, except when the app is killed. I want it to open the app when it's closed and then send `invokeMethod` once it's open. Currently it just does nothing when the app is killed.

Maybe there is a completely different approach. What is the best way to open a Flutter app from a widget while passing a message at the same time?